# vb.net: Using a Button on a Form to open another form, doesn't work

Tags: vb.net, forms

I encounter the following scenarios when I try to use 2 forms. My workflow is as follows:

(1) Load `Form1`.

(2) A click on `button1` on `Form1` closes `Form1` and opens `Form2`.

**Solution A: If I use the following code:**

```
Dim oForm As New Form2
oForm.ShowDialog()
Me.Close()
```

Then `Form1` will be under `Form2` (`Form1` still opens).

**Solution B: If I use the following code:**

```
Dim oForm As New Form2
oForm.Show()
Me.Close()
```

Then `Form1` closes and `Form2` opens, but `Form1` is not on the top layer.

I have looked through the solutions for this, most propose solution B, but for me, both solutions won't work the way I want. Can anybody tell me the reason?

Comment: Are you building a login dialogue?

Comment: See my answer on a login scenario

Comment: I feel like we are having to play 20 questions in order to find out essential information about what you are attempting. You need to put some effort in creating an example that will demonstrate your issue or post the code that you are using.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
Dim oForm as New Form2

oForm.Show()
```

and on Load event of form2

```
Form1.Hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use form.bringtofront() if you want to see the opening Form in the front, I m little confused though about what you are trying to do

Comment: Hi, by using this, Form1 closed, Form2 not opened.

Comment: If you use Dim formsecond As New Form2() formsecond.show() formsecond.bringtofront() me.hide() or me.close(), it should work, I dont see why it would not work

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it this way:

```
Dim oForm As New Form2()

Me.Hide()
oForm.ShowDialog()

Me.Close()
```

Comment: Thanks Baumi, I try this one but only Form1 closed, Form2 not appear.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your are building a log-in dialogue... if so, or something similar, try this..

Open your main form first... (Form 2), have form2 `showdialog` (modally) form1... this will put form1 on top of form2.

Add a property to form 1, that gets set depending on what happens there.. sucessfull login for instance.

Close form 1 from its own methods... (after successful authentication), set the property before closing.

On form2, read this property of form1, and then dispose form1, and decide what to do... if unsuccessful login, show the login form again, end app. If successful, just gracefully exit out of the method that showed form1. Your form 2 is now the only form open.

Start with Form2

**Form2_load**

```
dim f1 as new form1
f1.showdialog
if f1.someproperty = somevalue then

 ' do something here, for instance, pop the form again, if you did not get what you were lookign for...

end if

'gracefully let the function end and form2 is now the only open form..

'dispose of form1. form1's close call does not dispose it, because it was opened modally. (showdialog)

f1.dispose
f1 = nothing
```

in form1, depending on what you are doing, set the custom property and call me.close, this will exit the form, and run the next code in form2.

Comment: Hi Louis, thanks for your answer, I am not use log-in dialog, what I do is build a dll.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Dim oForm As New Form2

oForm.Show()

Me.Visible = False
```

You would to close your first form and this close your program. If you set him on invisible, he is not closed.

Answer (score -1):

Just go to `form2`  and write the `Form1.hide()` . I tried to close `form1` but it closed my whole program.

```
Public Class Form2
    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Form1.Hide()
    End Sub
End Class
```